# User assigned Exchange Admin role via Role Enabled Security Group unable to access EAC, but able to use management shell

Tags: azure-active-directory

As the title says, I have a user "User1" in a group "Techs" and "Techs" is a Role Enabled Azure AD, Cloud Only, Security Group that is assigned both the Exchange Administrator, Helpdesk Administrator and Exchange Recipients Administrator roles.

User1 is able to powershell and use most cmdlets for mailbox management, but is unable to access the EAC. Attempting to access EAC sends User1 to a mailbox management page for their own mailbox, and attempting to Edit Mailbox Properties for a user in the Microsoft 365 Portal greets User1 with a 403 forbidden page.

Direct assignment of exchange admin role works, but defeats the purpose of using a group. Anyone else experience this or know how I can fix it?

Comment: I don't experience the same behavior as yours. I can use a user which is in an AAD group (which is assigned both the Exchange Administrator) to access EAC. Please check if the user is assigned Exchange Administrator role in Azure Portal -> User1 -> Assigned roles
. And try to sign in https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com with User1 in an inprivate window.

Comment: Ok. So that is INCREDIBLY annoying. That direct admin link works. Every other “normal” way does not.

Comment: Also, my user does have the role listed but it is group assigned not direct assigned. When I direct assign it, normal access to EAC is restored...

Comment: I'm not sure what is the other “normal” way as you mentioned. For the new EAC, there are two methods to access it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-admin-center#get-to-the-new-exchange-admin-center. Both of them work for me. I'll provide more details in the answer below. If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is possible to switch back to the existing EAC (often called the "classic" EAC), but at a future date, the classic EAC will be retired.

But I suggest not to use "classic" EAC for work because according to my test, [the methods listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-admin-center#get-to-the-classic-exchange-admin-center) cannot allow the exchange admin to manage the mailboxes in the tenant.

It's recommended to access new EAC using [these 2 methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-admin-center#get-to-the-new-exchange-admin-center).

> 1. Sign in to Microsoft 365 or Office 365 using your work or school account.
> 2. In the left navigation pane, navigate to **Admin centers** > **Exchange**.
>
> You can also get to the new Exchange admin center directly by using
> the URL https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com and signing in using your
> credentials.

As the document suggests, **Be sure to use a private browsing session (not a regular session) to access the Exchange admin center using the direct URL. This will prevent the credential that you are currently logged on with from being used.**

In this way, your user which is assigned Exchange Admin role with Group inherit way should be able to access EAC successfully.

Comment: With my user that has the role assigned via group cannot access the New or Old EAC via the Admin Centers > Exchange method, only direct link works. Private browser session or not. If I add Exchange Admin directly to this user then they are able to. It seems that the Exchange Admin Role in a Group assignment doesn't work everywhere

Comment: @nathank1989 Different from your behavior. My Exchange Admin Role in a Group assignment works fine. You can raise a support ticket on O365 portal / Azure portal for further confirmation. Tenant management ticket is free.